# How to measure the performance of web flux intermediate operations?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I couldn't find a better way to measure the performance of web flux intermediate operations which involves cache/db/service lookups? Here is the sample code

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> registerEndpoints(){
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/hello/{name}/address"), handleRoute());

    }

    private HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> handleRoute() {
        return request -> {
            log.info("handleRoute start");
            Mono<ServerResponse> personInfo = Mono.just(request.pathVariable("name"))
                    .flatMap(this::handleDBLookup) //lookup person details from DB. 
                    .map(this::enrichData) //in memory operations
                    .flatMap(data -> ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(data), String.class));
            log.info("handleRoute end");
            return personInfo;
        };
    }
```

I need to measure the performance of

1. Overall handler execution time
2. DB lookup execution time
3. Data enrichment execution time

Adding start and end times at each method are not helping due to reactive nature of flow.Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timed` operator to measure the reactive part. For example to measure DB lookup:

```java
Mono.just(request.pathVariable("name")
    .flatMap(s -> handleDBLookup()
        .timed()
        .doOnNext(timed -> System.out.println(timed.elapsed()))
        .map(Timed::get)
    )
```

One drawback here is that timed operator only works if you have an `onNext` event. If the chain has error or completes empty, then it's not executed. To work that around you can use `materialize`/`dematerialize` as below:

```java
handleDBLookup()
    .materialize()
    .timed()
    .doOnNext(timed -> System.out.println(timed.elapsed()))
    .map(Timed::get)
    .dematerialize()
```

Comment: thank you Martin. I will try the above approach.